# How to use RxTextView switchMap with Flowable data?

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-android, rx-java2

Debouncing the search input values, I want to use `switchMap()` with method which returns `Flowable<List<T>>` I have edited my code using what @Maxim Ostrovidov suggest, now with `debounce` I added the 3 lines, as want to go over list convert to other time and receive list, but doesn't work. I used these 3 lines in other case it works, but not with `debounce` and `switchMap`

```
.flatMapIterable(items -> items)
        .map(Product::fromApi)
        .toList()




  subscription = RxTextView.textChangeEvents(searchInput)
            .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
            .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .switchMap(event -> getItems(searchInput.getText().toString()))
            .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
            .map(Product::fromApi)
            .toList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .subscribe(/../);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no `Observable.switchMapFlowable` operator [yet](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4853), you have to manually convert your stream using `toObservable` or `toFlowable` (depends on what type of stream you are planning to get eventually):

```
// Observable stream
RxTextView.textChangeEvents(searchInput)
    .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
    .switchMap(event -> yourFlowable(event).toObservable())
    ...

// Flowable stream
RxTextView.textChangeEvents(searchInput)
    .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER) //or any other strategy
    .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
    .switchMap(event -> yourFlowable(event))
    ...
```